# Same executable, different filename changes performance

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I have an executable (neural network simulation software) developed in C++ and wxWidgets, compiled in Visual Studio 2010. On my development machine (Windows 7 64bit) it was running very slowly, taking 130 seconds instead of 14 seconds for the same run. I finally discovered that it works fine if I just changed the filename of the exe. To hunt for the cause I've turned off antivirus (Microsoft Security Essentials, searched the registry and event logs, but found nothing. Doesn't matter if it's compiled with wxWidgets DLL or static library, 32bit or 64bit.

What could possibly be the problem? Processor affinity and priority is all normal. Only clue is that the process also uses more memory (130meg instead of 90meg).

Comment: Did you have Visual Studio open?  Could it have been running a debugger on it?

Comment: It does seem like a debugging type slowdown, but makes no difference if Visual Studio is closed.